# How does webpack compress link CSS files in HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I am a newcomer to webpack, In HTML, I want to compress and reference link CSS files

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/common.css">    
</head>

<body>
  <div class="common-red">
  hello;
  </div>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`js` file:

```
import "common.css"
```

This is my profile:

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output:{
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist')
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:[
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "style-loader",
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test:/\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use:[
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test:/\.(html)$/,
                use:{
                    loader: "html-loader",
                    options:{
                        attrs:['img:src']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins:[
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
            styles: {
              name: 'styles',
              test: /\.css$/,
              chunks: 'all',
              enforce: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

I want to compress the link CSS code on HTML, but I tried to manipulate it, I can't package the link css file on html, but I can package css in the `js` file.

what should I do?

**Expectations**:

Package the linked css file in HTML and reference it

Can you help me?

thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the MiniCssExtractPlugin? https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/

Comment: @ BugsArePeopleToo I tried. It didn't work

Comment: Are you importing the CSS into your app? import is necessary for webpack to see the files.

Comment: have you tried removing style-loader in rules for css  ? just a guess

Comment: @ BugsArePeopleToo  This plugin only supports CSS compression in JS and does not support HTML link CSS files.

Comment: @ Anil Namde What should I do? I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your css into your js file so that MiniCssExtractPlugin can work

Something like this

app.js

```
import "css/Admin/admin.css";

import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this method. It's not working.

Comment: There are no mistakes，I was surprised.

Comment: Sorry for missing one case. If the link CSS file is not deleted, the Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'common. CSS 'Error will be reported